# Error 429: Start an Approval error in Power Automate

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

When I create an PowerApps to Integrate with Power Automate,

Its shown me the error as below:

[image]

When I run in default environment , the Power Automate flow is working.

But when I run in other enviroment , the Flow is not working.

Any permission or steps, I'm missing ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having the same problem you will need to be a global admin and then do the following:

- Get an F2 flow licence for the account you are using
- Go to the flow app and then from settings choose the admin centre
- choose the 'envronments' tab on the left
- select your default environemnt
- click 'create database' and follow the instructions

[Ref Solution](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Action-Start-an-approval-failed/m-p/174930#M26292)

Comment: Its means that the approval process only can work in Default Environment?

Comment: @EngSoonCheah if my answer helps could you please mark it as solved.